# Is it illegal to give a financed car back to its owner even though I made an oral agreement to make payments?

Tags: financing

I was in a relationship and she financed a car for me. It was verbally agreed that I would make the payments. Things went south, we're no longer together but I have paid the car for the last 3 years but financially cannot afford it any longer. Is it legal to return the vehicle to the owner in this case her.

Comment: Legal questions require a location tag, and this might be more suitable for http://law.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Does the car have equity? (How much is the car loan payoff and how much is the car worth?)

Comment: I agree with the legal comment. Not sure how oral agreements will hold up, especially when you held you end up of the bargain and you can see proof of money being transferred through her account to pay for it. In any case, somebody has to be paying the bill, or else your ex will be considered delinquent in the vehicle's payment, which would go on her record for some time.

Comment: Does she not want the car?

Comment: Are you saying she paid for the car and you agreed to pay her back by making payments o her? Or did she agree to a financing deal (maybe because she had better credit) and you've been making the payments to the lender on her loan?

Comment: If by legal, you mean criminal, then that almost certainly doesn't apply. This sounds like a contract issue, which is a civil matter. Contractually, you probably have some liability for the remaining payments, but without more details on the original agreement and your payments to date, it's hard to say what that liability is, and how returning the car would affect it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because absent any indication of location as well as lack of clarity as to whose name(s) are on the car loan as the borrowers and whose name(s) are on the title to the car as owners, this question is unanswerable. Should the OP deign to supply this information, I will be glad to vote to re-open it.

Answer (score 1):

So you bought a car, she signed the financing contract, for the last three years you have paid for the car and driven the car, and now for whatever reason you cannot afford to make the payments.

Financing a car for someone else is something people should never do, so your ex-girlfriend made a mistake there; she is lucky you behaved in a decent way for the last three years (and that you had the money to behave in a decent way).

Your possibilities are: 1. Keep the car, and discuss with your ex-girlfriend how much you are able to pay. She would have to cough up the difference, which is better for her than having to make full payments. 2. Return the car to her. She has then likely two cars, and has to make full payments. She would probably sell your car for as much as possible to pay as much as possible of the loan back, or sell her own car.

In either case, she will suffer financial loss, and it's your decision morally what you will do to make up for that loss. As I said, financing a car for someone else is a HUGE mistake, so you are fine legally - but not morally. I can't myself imagine ever financing my lifestyle at the expense of an ex-girlfriend.